# Show ACF in customer account dashboard - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I would like to show a custom welcome message for each of my registered shop customers. Something like "Welcome `CUSTOMERNAME`! You have been with us for one year now. To say thanks, we are giving you a discount on everything in our shop of 10%."

I have created a custom field `welcome_message` with the plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/advanced-custom-fields/) and would like to show the value of it in the account dashboard of my customers at frontend.

At the backend, I am showing the textarea at the user profile page and I am adding the field with this code:

`$message = get_field( 'welcome_message' );
echo esc_attr( $message );`

This code is placed here: /wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/woocommerce/myaccount/dashboard.php

But somehow the value is not coming up. I have also tried it with simply `the_field('welcome_message');` or to add `[acf field="{$welcome_message}"]` at the account page in WordPress but that didn't work either. Somehow the value is not coming through.

I hope someone could help me out a litte.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's necessary that get_field function is connected to user.

Eg:

```
<?php
$variable = get_field('field_name', 'user_1');
?>
```

In case of repeater field:

```
<?php if( have_rows('repeater', 'user_1') ): ?>
<ul>
<?php while( have_rows('repeater', 'user_1') ): the_row(); ?>
    <li><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for you help but this didn't work. I am getting the current user id with $current_user_id = get_current_user_id(); and setting $variable = get_field('field_name', $current_user_id);.

Comment: It's wrong, if you see example, is required "user_" prefix before user_id.
your correct way is: $variable = get_field('field_name', 'user_' . $current_user_id);